# Oracle string search related query to find user names that matches search?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am bit new to SQL help me to write a simple query

suppose table name is "Users" and below column name is "DomainUser"

```
ac\jason_mirabello  
mac\jason_thompson  
nyc\jason_graham  
jdb\jason_bates
```

i got user name that comes after '\' 
so i need to search through user name to find if a user exist so i need to exclude domain part

help me writing a query to achieve above in oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a LIKE operator:

```
SELECT * FROM users
 WHERE domainuser LIKE '%\jason_graham';
```

but I like using a regular expression here in case the backslash `\` doesn't exist:

```
SELECT * FROM users
 WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(domainuser, '[^\\]+$') = 'jason_graham';
```

The difficulty with both of the above queries is that neither will use an index. What you can do is create a function-based index which will work with the latter query:

```
CREATE INDEX domainuser_un ON users (REGEXP_SUBSTR(domainuser, '[^\\]+$'));
```

It might also be helpful to use `LOWER()` so that the index is "case-insensitive" (just make sure to convert the search term to lowercase too!) - assuming your usernames are not case-sensitive:

```
CREATE INDEX domainuser_un ON users (LOWER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(domainuser, '[^\\]+$')));
```

[Here is an explanation of the regular expression I used.](https://regex101.com/r/nY0oL3/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try using like clause as below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users
WHERE DomainUser LIKE '%jason_graham'
```